# WM_COPYDATA with and without quotes yields different results

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe, wm-copydata

Using WM_COPYDATA to pass command line params to another app instance with Delphi XE as follows:

```
function DAppInstance.SendParamsToPrevInstance(AWindowHandle: THandle): Boolean;
var
  copyData: TCopyDataStruct;
  cmdParams : string;
  i : integer;
begin
  cmdParams := '';
  for i := 1 to ParamCount do
    cmdParams := cmdParams + ParamStr(i); //#1
  //cmdParams := cmdParams + '"' + ParamStr(i) + '" '; //#2
  //cmdParams := cmdParams + format('"%s" ', [ParamStr(i)]); //#3
  //cmdParams := cmdParams + format('%s;', [ParamStr(i)]); //#4

  copyData.lpData := pchar(cmdParams);
  copyData.cbData := 1 + (bytelength(cmdParams));
  copyData.dwData := WaterMark;  //ID for APP

  result := SendMessage(AWindowHandle, 
    WM_COPYDATA, 
    Application.Handle, 
    LPARAM(@copyData)) = 1;
end;
```

yields different results if the strings are quoted / appended to.

if #1 is used - the string comes in clean but is not usable if not quoted as filenames can have spaces and this:

```
C:\Users\MX4399\Research\delphi\instance\doc with spaces.doc
```

will be see as 3 paramaters in the end, while using #2 to quote the strings, or appending anything (#3, #4) causes

```
"C:\Users\MX4399\Research\delphi\instance\doc with spaces.doc"'#$FF00'궳獧
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant `copyData.cbdata := 1 * SizeOf(Char) + ...` instead of just `1 + ...`.

Comment: +1 Yes that would explain it. Of course it would be easier to write `SizeOf(Char)*(1+Length(cmdParams))` than use a special bytelength function.

Comment: Actually, I think it would be safer to use the byte count in the receiving code and not bother marshalling the zero terminator. Relying on an WM_COPYDATA being zero-terminated is a recipe for buffer overruns.

Comment: `ByteLength()` does the `SizeOf(Char)*Lenght(String)` calculation for you actually, it uses `StringElementSize()` instead of `SizeOf()`). It returns the number of bytes, not characters, used by a string. `WM_COPYDATA` expects a byte count.

Comment: @Remy Yes, but it misses the null terminator and we assume that the recipient code is treating lpData as a C string.

Comment: Changed it to `copyData.cbdata := byteLength(#0) + (bytelength(cmdParams));` and it works fine - rather logical

Comment: Taking the byte length of the null teminator literal doesn't guarantee the correct byte count to match the string encoding. You should use `StringElementSize(cmdParams)` instead of `ByteLength(#0)`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that @TOndrej has spotted the main cause of the problem.  However, I think you have a second more subtle bug.

Your app which receives the `WM_COPYDATA` message is, I think, treating `lpData` as a null-terminated string. If the data is malformed then you will have a buffer overrun. I believe that is exactly what is happening in your examples but it just turns out to be benign. The marshalling of `WM_COPYDATA` copies just the size of buffer specified in `cbData`. You must make sure you don't read beyond it. A malicious app could send you a `WM_COPYDATA` message with data to make you do just that. Instead I recommend you use `cbData` when reading.

So to send the string you write:

```
copyData.lpData := PChar(cmdParams);
copyData.cbData := ByteLength(cmdParams))
copyData.dwData := WaterMark;
```

And then when you receive it you allocate a buffer and copy to that buffer based on the value of `cbData`.

```
SetString(cmdParams, PChar(copyData.lpData), copyData.cbData div SizeOf(Char));
```

Comment: you are right, that will be safer, I will investigate. Odd though that modifying paramstr(n) causes this not not if appended to.

Comment: You were just lucky before. The code was broken even without appending.

Answer (score 4):

On a separate but related note, rather then using `ParamStr()` (which itself has a number of known bugs) to parse the original command-line and rebuild a new string from it, you could just use `GetCommandLine()` to get the original command-line instead and send it as-is.